# same print statement yielding different results

Tags: fortran

A sample code is below to indicate the problem I am having.  This is as minimal/complete I can make it in order to reproduce the problem I'm having.  My problem is that the same print statement, three lines apart, is yielding two different results.  The first print statement yields the correct result while the second one yields the wrong result.  Am I re-writing the variable definitions within these 3 lines?  How come when I move the print statment down 3 lines I get a different, incorrect result?  The print statements are shown below.  Since the variables are somehow being changed, this causes a lot of problems in the expected results later on in my code.  However I just want to understand whats going on with these print statements.  Thanks.

```
Module Sample

integer :: n,m 

contains 

subroutine Sub1(localf0)
implicit none

complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10), intent(inout) :: localf0
complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10) :: localf1
complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10) :: Deriv0, Deriv1


Deriv0 = Deriv(localf0)

do while (norm2(abs(Deriv0)) > 0.000001) 

   print*, abs(localf1(1,1))-abs(localf0(1,1))  
   localf1   = localf0 +1.0*Deriv(localf0) 
   Deriv0 = Deriv(localf0)
   Deriv1 = Deriv(localf1)
   print*, abs(localf1(1,1))-abs(localf0(1,1))  

end do

end subroutine Sub1

function  Deriv(func)

implicit none

real :: x, y
complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10), intent(in) :: func
complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10) :: localf,Deriv

localf = func

do m=-9,9
do n=-9,9

      x = real(n)*0.1
      y = real(m)*0.1
      localf(n,m)= cmplx(z1(x,y),z2(x,y))

end do
end do

do m=-9,9
do n=-9,9

    Deriv(n,m) = (localf(n+1,m)+localf(n-1,m)+localf(n,m+1)+localf(n,m-1)-4*localf(n,m))/0.01 

end do
end do

end function Deriv

End Module Sample

program MyProgram

  use Sample
  implicit none
  complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10) :: localf0,localf1

  do m=-10,10
  do n=-10,10

       localf0(n,m) =    cmplx(z1(real(n)*0.1,real(m)*0.1) , z2(real(n)*0.1,real(m)*0.1))
       localf1   = localf0 + 1.0*Deriv(localf0)

  end do
  end do

  call  Sub1(localf0)

end program
```

Comment: Are you aware of that `func0` and `func1` are being redefined in the function?

Comment: @francescalus No I did not realize that, I know you're right but I still don't see how I'm doing that. How can I fix that, is that why they get redefined as each other and the difference yields 0 in the second print statement ? I do not mean to be doing that... Thanks

Comment: it seems pretty obvious the statement `func(n,m)= cmplx..` is changing `func`. In fortran arrays are passed by reference. If you want to only change a local copy you need to actually define a local array and make a copy.

Comment: @agentp Thanks, however what seems pretty obvious to you is not obvious at all to me. I've been very stuck on this sadly. How do I define a local array and make a copy? I'm pretty new to Fortran so none of this is obvious whatsoever

Comment: `complex, dimension(-10:10,-10:10) :: localf` and  `localf=func`.  You should also add `intent(in)` to the declaration of `func` in `Deriv`

Comment: @agentp Thanks. I am trying to implement your suggestion into my code and figure out what you mean. I'm not entirely clear as to if I'm using localf or func0 in the subroutine. I'll try to figure it out and update the post.

Comment: my earlier comment re: defining `localf` applied to the *function* `Deriv`

Comment: @agentp I just updated my post based on your suggestion.  I think I am now getting even further away from fixing the issue since I'm certain I implemented your suggestion very wrong.  Sorry about that, I just don't know what exactly you mean.  Should there still be a func0,func1 in my subroutine?  Should there be any func at all anymore, are you suggesting changing all func to Localf? If I change all the 'func' to 'Localf', isn't that just the same code?

Comment: better. Note now you are not using `func` in `Deriv` at all. Presumably you need it for the boundary values which are not set in the first loop but are needed in the second loop.  Do that simply by copying the whole thing. `localf=func` (before the first loop )

Comment: @agentp Okay, I added that before the first loop.  Does it seem Okay now? I'm not sure it is since when I print out the value of abs(localf0(1,1)) I get zero which isn't right.  In my original post, the value of abs(func0(1,1)) was not zero, it was correct though.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `localf1` in your main program in unrelated to the `localf1` in the subroutine `Sub1`. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with using the same symbol name in both places, but it seems to be confusing you as you seem to be thinking they are related.  the first time you use `localf1` in the *subroutine* it is undefined ( so probably 0 ).  As another matter `localf0` never changes in the `while` loop so that loop will run forever computing the same result over and over.

Comment: @agentp in my original post though abs(func0(1,1)) printed the correct value. Now abs(localf0(1,1)) doesn't print out the correct value it prints zero. You're very correct I'm confusing the localf1 in my subroutine and program. How do you suggest I fix this though? Can you perhaps post any code? Code will help me opposed to  all the Fortran terminology I clearly don't get. All the comments are helpful but have made me more confused to be honest with you . My original code at least calculated my initial condition correct. Now that's not being computed correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I've run it there is a insidious thing here that I frankly think the compiler should throw an error on. (Why I made this an answer rather than comment)

You have made `n,m` module variables, effectively making them global variables and you use the same `n,m` in the main program loop and in the loops inside the function.

Your function `deriv` *changes the values* of `n` and `m`. (They return as the end value of its last loop) so that the main program loop does not complete.

You can see this if you put in the main loop:

```
 print*,m,n
 localf1 = localf0 + 1.0*deriv(localf0)
 print*,m,n
```

you get :

> -10 -10
>
> 10 10

and the loop exits.. ( the `10,10` is one more than the the loop limit of `9,9` inside the function.. )

What you should do is remove the `integer n,m` from the module. Declare `n,m` integers where needed (That is declare individually in `deriv` and in `MyProgram` )

You may note also there is no reason for `localf1` to be assigned inside the main program loop in the first place (or set at all for that matter since you never use it ).  Removing that assignment would fix the issue as well, but I'd still recommend changing the `n,m` declarations to local.

Note with that fixed you still have the problem that nothing changes with each iteration of the `while` loop so it loops indefinitely printing the same values. I guess you want to update `localf0=localf1` at the end of the loop.

Comment: This is a good point (and good advice to have loop variables local), but the compiler has no obligation to detect this programming error.  Especially when it is made hard to do by using module variables.  Perhaps "would be nice" rather than "should".

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to think about all this and implement it all in the code now. I'll have questions, but need to work it out myself first . I'll post my questions here when I understand more. I'm glad you also found the issue with the integers n,m; I think it's obvious I never would have realized any of this so thanks.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for your comment also. I'll make sure all loop variables are local variables.

Comment: @agentp I implemented everything you said and I do not have any questions surprisingly.  This all makes sense to me.  I removed the integers n,m from the module and put them as local loop variables.   I added in the line localf0=localf1 to the end of the loop so that it updates now.  Thanks for your answer.